# Sql index storage and locating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a general question about how in general SQL servers store their indexes and how the index locate the record (row(s)). When an index is created on a table, is all the index stored in-memory? When a Sql server starts, is all the index loaded from disk into memory?

Another question is, how does an index find the row in the table? Is it through hashing function like an index is found and the location is hashed into some location on a disk? How does the data is stored in disk? By location? It kind of puzzles me, because the data retrieval is fast in Sql servers.

Comment: can't you http://www.google.com it?

Comment: This may help http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: "is all the index stored in-memory" - think about it for a while, you can answer that one (and the following) yourself.

Comment: While I agree that much of this info can be searched, knowing what to search for is key. Not everyone has a copy of [The Black Book](http://www.amazon.com/Transaction-Processing-Concepts-Techniques-Management/dp/1558601902) on their desk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is described in [Clustered Index Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> In SQL Server, indexes are organized as **B-trees**. Each page in an index B-tree is called an index node. The top node of the B-tree is called the root node. The bottom level of nodes in the index is called the leaf nodes. Any index levels between the root and the leaf nodes are collectively known as intermediate levels. In a clustered index, the leaf nodes contain the data pages of the underlying table. The root and intermediate level nodes contain index pages holding index rows. Each index row contains a key value and a pointer to either an intermediate level page in the B-tree, or a data row in the leaf level of the index. The pages in each level of the index are linked in a doubly-linked list.

[Non-clustered Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) are organized simialrly, also as B-Trees:

> Nonclustered indexes have the same B-tree structure as clustered indexes, except for the following significant differences:
>
> - The data rows of the underlying table are not sorted and stored in order based on their nonclustered keys.
> - The leaf layer of a nonclustered index is made up of index pages instead of data pages.

[B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) are described in Wikipedia:

> In computer science, a B-tree is a tree data structure that keeps data sorted and allows searches, sequential access, insertions, and deletions in logarithmic time. The B-tree is a generalization of a binary search tree in that a node can have more than two children

The [Searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Search) topic describes the b-tree search algorithm:

> Searching is similar to searching a binary search tree. Starting at the root, the tree is recursively traversed from top to bottom. At each level, the search chooses the child pointer (subtree) whose separation values are on either side of the search value.
>   Binary search is typically (but not necessarily) used within nodes to find the separation values and child tree of interest.

As for what is in-memory vs. what is on-disk, read about [Buffer Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337525%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> The buffer manager manages the functions for reading data or index pages from the database disk files into the buffer cache and writing modified pages back to disk. A page remains in the buffer cache until the buffer manager needs the buffer area to read in more data. Data is written back to disk only if it is modified. Data in the buffer cache can be modified multiple times before being written back to disk. For more information, see [Reading Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)s and [Writing Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337560%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).